# C++ , Student Class with set and get functions

Tags: c++, class, object

I've tried to write a class for a student information(name,IDno,and degree), this information will be printed on the screen; but I don't know where is the errors?!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Student {
private:
    char name;
    int idnumber;
    char degree;
public:
    Student(char,int,char);
    void setName(char n){name = n;}
    int getName(){return name;}
    void setIdnumber(char id){idnumber = id;}
    int getIdnumber(){return idnumber;}
    void setDegree(char d){degree = d;}
    int getDegree(){return degree;}
};
Student::Student(char n,int id,char d){
    name = n;
    idnumber = id;
    degree = d;
}

int main(){
    Student s1, s2;
    s1.setName(Sara);
    s1.setIdnumber(333);
    s1.setDegree(A);
    s2.setName(Jack);
    s2.setIdnumber(222);
    s2.setDegree(B);
    cout << "name: " << s1.getName() << ",IDnumber: " << s1.getIdnumber() << ",Degree: " <<      s1.getDegree() << endl;
    cout << "name: " << s2.getName() << ",IDnumber: " << s2.getIdnumber() << ",Degree: " << s2.getDegree() << endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've barely told us anything. We know less than you about the errors.

Comment: Please post what the error and what line the compiler says is generating it please.

Comment: I would re-read a book on C++ programming as you have lots of errors in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you have the following issues:

```
 Student s1, s2;
```

This will try to call the `default constructor`. However, you defined a constructor that takes 3 parameters, which inhibits the compiler to generate a default constructor for you, so you will fail to create those objects, which effectively makes your follow up member function calls fail.

```
s1.setName(Sara);
```

`setName` takes `char` type as parameter type, if you mean string literal `"Sara"`, then you will have trouble. Similar issues can be found in other function calls. You should fix this.

Meanwhile, you should prefer to use `member initialization list` instead of using assignment in constructor body to initialize your members.

```
  Student::Student(char n,int id,char d): name(n), idnumber(id), degree(d){}
```

make sure that your members are declared in order of `name, idnumber, degree`.

Answer (score 1):

char is a single character, not a string. try using std::string instead.

also, to declare a string literal,  surround your string in quotes ""
eg:

```
s1.setName("Sara");
```

also, to use std::string, you will need to `#include <string>`

Comment: "Sara" is string literal, cannot pass to member function that accepts `char`.

Comment: oh ffs I didn't even see all those... it's like they haven't even run this through a compiler. maybe they just need correct code and they thought using SO as their error parser would be easier than installing a compiler...

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your code

```
char name;
```

name here is just a char literal so it will only store one literal while you are trying to pass string Sara to it. So change **name** to array or pointer

```
char name[10] or char *name
```

Also while passing name pass it with double quotes like "Sara". Change all the formal arguments in the functions to char array or pointer.

```
Student s1, s2;
```

Here while creating objects s1 and s2 it will call default constructor, which you have not provided, So include default constructor in your code

```
Student(){}

s1.setDegree(A);
```

Here you are trying to pass a literal not a variable so quote it

```
s1.setDegree('A');
```

C++ provides string datatype which is much easy to use wrt to char or char[], so use it. You can operate upon it like you use other datatype like int, double.
That will avoid your hassle to specify array length, using strcpy() to copy strings.

```
string name;
```